# Changes required in makefile of project run on 64 bit system to 32 bit system

Tags: compilation, 32bit-64bit

What changes would be required in Makefile of 64 bit system so that it can be build on 32 bit system.

On 64 bit server :

```
bash-3.2$ uname -a
2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On 32 bit server:

```
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-100.34.1.el6uek.i686 #1 SMP Wed May 25 17:28:36 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

On make error is displayed as:

```
usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `./lib/libxml2.a(parser.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Comment: It certainly depends on the contents of the Makefile, i.e. impossible to say in general! The Makefile itself is unaffected. But options to compiler, etc. may have to be changed...

Comment: error is coming on make as :usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `./lib/libxml2.a(parser.o)' is incompatible with i386 output

Answer (score 0):

By the error there, it sounds like you're trying to use a 64-bit .o file... Is parser.o something that you're compiling yourself?